# how to disable login screen java spring boot security 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-security

how to disable login screen java spring boot security 6 with config file. Here is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http = http.cors(cr -> {
                        cr.disable();
            });
            http = http.csrf(cs -> {
                        cs.disable();
                    });
            http = http.sessionManagement(ss -> {
                        ss.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                    });
            http = http.authorizeRequests(au -> {
                        au.anyRequest().permitAll();
                    });
            http = http.formLogin(fl -> {
                        fl.disable();
                    });
            http = http.httpBasic(hb -> {
                        hb.disable();
            });
    return http.build();
}}
```

When I run with this config it redirect everything to a login screen with a random generated password. I want to disable the redirect, login screen and generated password.

Comment: Do you want to disable security completely? (you authorize all requests)
Also, did you check whether your security configuration is part of your component scan? (You probably did, just checking.)

Comment: How to check whether your security configuration is part of your component scan? I added @ComponentScan on top of class but it still the same. I want to disable the web login part so my GET api and POST login api can be access.

Comment: @ChristianHujer I've got it. My Config was not in the right pakage. It's in Config but should have been com.example.api.Config and the same with my Controller.

Comment: To disable generated password, you have to define the`spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password` configuration properties in the application.properties file.